# Ubuntu 14.10 thinks my laptop is a phone

Tags: 14.10

So I updated to 14.10, now System settings changed to an obviously Android-like UI that keeps crashing because I'm not on a tablet/phone, but on my good old laptop. Is it the intended behavior, I mean Ubuntu is now meant for touch-based small screen devices only?

Comment: Hmm, you should have done something wrong because this should not happen if you used standart installation . If you done normal update maybe you experimented with Ubuntu touch related PPA's? Try to check and if they exists remove them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just use the localized version of Settings for desktop settings. The English version gives the phone settings. I don't know why the Ubuntu 14.10 upgrade pulled that it, but be careful not to remove it, as you will not be able to open any of the system settings without it (I know, it's a mess).